# How we can display Natural landmark on google earth using google earth api

Tags: google-earth

How can I display Natural landmarks on Google Earth using Google Earth API?

Answer (score 0):

The layers in Google Earth API are limited to borders, buildings, roads, trees, and terrain.

For those specific layers, you can enable them with

```
ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_BORDERS, true);
```

**But note that the Google Earth API has been deprecated as of December 12th, 2014. The API will continue to work on supported browsers until December 12th, 2015, and will shut down on that date.**

The Google Earth API was created to embed Google Earth within a web page to be viewed by a web browser. More details at https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/layers
 and
https://developers.google.com/earth/

You can use [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/web/) to view natural landmarks and embed the view in a web page. There is an Earth mode but it's not quite Google Earth.

Using the Google Earth desktop application, you can view any of the natural landmarks by just typing its name in the search box (e.g. Grand Canyon) and flying to that location.